# Locking and synchronization issues in multithreaded pthread_t?

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I'm learning how to use `pthread_t` to synchronize and communicate multithreading.
The introduction to the function manual is:

> The mutex object referenced by mutex is locked by calling
> pthread_mutex_lock(). If the mutex is already locked, the calling
> thread blocks until the mutex becomes available.

I saw the following piece of code online and it worked. I am very confused about the result of the run.

The first part of the run result looks like this.

```
djh: Line: 33, i = 1
thread1: lock 35
thread1: unlock 45
thread1 will sleep 1s in Line: 46

djh: Line: 58, i = 1
thread2: lock 60
thread2: wait 1 62
djh: Line: 33, i = 2
thread1: lock 35
thread1: unlock 45
thread1 will sleep 1s in Line: 46

djh: Line: 33, i = 3
thread1: lock 35
thread1:signal 1 37
thread1:signal 2 39
thread1 will sleep 1s in Line: 40
thread1: unlock 45
thread1 will sleep 1s in Line: 46
```

But obviously this is unreasonable. Because the `pthread_mutex_lock` function is called twice in a row. But the manual says that when a process is locked, other threads calling this function will be **blocked**.

But this paragraph in the output above seems to defy that interpretation.

> thread2: lock 60
> thread2: wait 1 62
> djh: Line: 33, i = 2
> thread1: lock 35

That is when thread 2 runs for the first time. After thread 2 executes pthread_mutex_lock to lock, it enters the if statement, and then the pthread_cond_signal function makes thread 2 wait. At this point, thread 1 starts executing again, and it locks again.   Why is thread 1 not blocked at this time? Thread 2 is not unlocked.
Thread 1 is not blocked, and keeps running until i = 3, allowing it to enter the if statement, notifying thread 2. This is weird.

And the role of the pthread_cond_signal function is also confusing. Why design this function? Isn't it the same as locking? For example I redeclare a lock. I do locks wherever pthread_cond_signal is executed, and unlocks wherever pthread_cond_signal is executed. Is this the same effect?

Really thanks!!!

```
#include <pthread.h>
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 
 
 pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;/*初始化互斥锁*/
 pthread_cond_t cond = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;/*初始化条件变量*/
 
 
 void *thread1(void *);
 void *thread2(void *);
 
 
 int i=1;
 
 
 int main(void)
 {
 pthread_t t_a;
 pthread_t t_b;
 pthread_create(&t_a,NULL,thread1,(void *)NULL);/*创建进程t_a*/
 pthread_create(&t_b,NULL,thread2,(void *)NULL); /*创建进程t_b*/
 pthread_join(t_a, NULL);/*等待进程t_a结束*/
 pthread_join(t_b, NULL);/*等待进程t_b结束*/
 pthread_mutex_destroy(&mutex);
 pthread_cond_destroy(&cond);
 exit(0);
 }
 void *thread1(void *junk)
 {
    for(i=1;i<=6;i++)
    {
        printf("djh: Line: %d, i = %d\n", __LINE__, i);
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);/*锁住互斥量*/
        printf("thread1: lock %d\n", __LINE__);
      if(i%3==0){
        printf("thread1:signal 1 %d\n", __LINE__);
        pthread_cond_signal(&cond);/*条件改变，发送信号，通知t_b进程*/
        printf("thread1:signal 2 %d\n", __LINE__);
        printf("%s will sleep 1s in Line: %d \n", __FUNCTION__, __LINE__);
        sleep(1);
      }
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);/*解锁互斥量*/
        printf("thread1: unlock %d\n", __LINE__);
        printf("%s will sleep 1s in Line: %d \n\n", __FUNCTION__, __LINE__);
        sleep(1);
        
    }
 }
 
 
 void *thread2(void *junk)
 {
    while(i<6)
    {
        printf("djh: Line: %d, i = %d\n", __LINE__, i);
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
        printf("thread2: lock %d\n", __LINE__);
        if(i%3!=0){
        printf("thread2: wait 1 %d\n", __LINE__);
        pthread_cond_wait(&cond,&mutex);/*解锁mutex，并等待cond改变*/
        printf("thread2: wait 2 %d\n", __LINE__);
      }
      pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
      printf("thread2: unlock %d\n", __LINE__);
      printf("%s will sleep 1s in Line: %d \n\n", __FUNCTION__, __LINE__);
      sleep(1);
    }
 }
```

Comment: Re “But obviously this is unreasonable. Because the `pthread_mutex_lock` function is called twice in a row.”: `thread2` calls `pthread_mutex_lock` and then calls `pthread_cond_wait`. The documentation for `pthread_cond_wait` says it atomically blocks the current thread (the one that called it) and releases the mutex. So `thread2` becomes blocked and the lock of `mutex` becomes available. So `thread1` gets the lock and runs.

Comment: Re, "`pthread_cond_signal`...is also confusing...Isn't it the same as locking?" Not the same at all. Read the man pages. `pthread_mutex_lock` waits until some other thread is not using the `mutex`. `pthread_cond_wait` _releases_ the `mutex`, waits for some other thread to signal the `cond` variable, and then re-locks the `mutex` before it returns. And, of course, `pthread_cond_signal` is what the `pthread_cond_wait` call is waiting for.

Comment: When pthread_cond_wait releases the lock, if another process locks it and then calls pthread_cond_signal, how does it relock?

Comment: In that case, @Gerrie, the awakened thread has to wait until the mutex becomes available for it to lock.  Its `pthread_cond_wait()` call does not return until the thread successfully re-locks the mutex.